# Recovering windows after installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, windows

Here is my story...
I had a dual booted PC with *Ubuntu* and *Windows 7*. It worked fine. But I forgot my admin password of *Ubuntu*. So I decided to uninstall my older version and reinstall a newer version of *Ubuntu*. But what I got what was a

```
grub rescue error
```

Then I installed *Ubuntu* with my USB without trying get *Windows* back. Now my PC automatically boots *Ubuntu*. So I downloaded a *Windows 7* ISO and used my USB to repair it. But when I load my USB in boot option menu, instead of asking me to install *Windows*, it shows the

```
0xc0000225 error
```

and asks me to insert a disk(which I've done using my USB).
What should I do to get *Windows 7* back (or course, without losing *Ubuntu*)?

Comment: That's a Windows boot error, which is off-topic here. Please ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: It smell like the installation media is corrupted. How did you create it?

Comment: Just select the error message you posted, "0xc0000225 error", then copy & paste it in to google. Follow any of the guides that will definitely pop up on how to resolve that windows BCD issue.

Comment: I thank everyone for considering my question. I solved the issue. The problem was at the partition scheme I used while creating bootable USB. I used GPT as partition scheme(and it worked for another PC, for some reason not on my desktop), which was default in Rufus. So I used MBR and it worked perfectly. If anyone knows why I would be grateful for your answer